# Can I put a 'tick' symbol on an HTML button using the 'value' attribute?

Tags: html

I don't want to use CSS, I just want to plainly insert a tick symbol from the character map.

Comment: Just google the words "unicode checkmark".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tick symbol in HTML/XHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658044/tick-symbol-in-html-xhtml)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can copy the following symbol and paste it to your Buttons value.

✓

like this

```
<input type="button" value="✓ Test" />
```

Comment: Make sure your page is saved and served as UTF-8, or another encoding that includes the tick character.

Comment: Else we can also use HTML entity `&#10003;`

Answer (score 2):

If you want ✓ symbol then simply use `&#10003;` html code in span.
It will work in most of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Font Awesome, just add 
    `<i class="icon-check-sign"></i>` icon-check-sign