# create a Tick symbol in HTML table

Tags: html, css

I want to output a tick symbol (like a check mark in American English) inside the  elements at the end of each row in my table (that's going in an eamil to be displayed on windows pc's running IE 8 and IE 10)

I have tried several different ways of doing this, with no luck.

Here is my HTML:

```
<td align="centre" style="font-family: wingdings; font-size:150%;font-weight:bold; font-color:green">&#10004;</TD>
```

I did try some of the suggestions [here on SO: 658044](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658044/tick-symbol-in-html-xhtml) but have had no success

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dont know what your issue is, but ie9 and ie10 works fine, can not test ie8 since jsfiddle doesnt seem to support ie8 properly http://jsfiddle.net/2hHVq/

Comment: What's the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/Kf36g/1/

Comment: it just prints a blank in the table cell - what font-family should I use?

Comment: Does it work in other browsers? Could u post a more complete HTML/CSS - there could be other styles overwriting inline one

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rKMw8/2/
What browser are you using?

Comment: Check out Fontello http://fontello.com/. If you need help setting it up let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use one of these codes:

```
<td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
```

or

```
<td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#x2714</td>
```

although **center** is correct. you can remove one of **text-align:center;** or **align="center"** optionaly, as you want.

Comment: and for "cross mark"
`<td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10008;</td>`

Answer (score 1):

You are using unicode, no need for a font family. Also, the style property is color, not font-color.

```
<td style="font-size:150%;font-weight:bold;color:green;">&#10004;</td>
```

Comment: so what should I use in my HTML then?