# How to display unicode chars using php?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm currently using php and zend 2, and trying to display this specific char ✔. I've tried this way:

```
<?php echo '<td>' . ($fiche['statut']==1? &#10004; :'') . '</td>'; ?>
```

But, doing that I'm getting the following error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&'

How to fix this, please ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add single quotes: `'&#10004'`

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658044/tick-symbol-in-html-xhtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotes:

```
<?php echo '<td>' . ($fiche['statut']==1? '&#10004;' :'') . '</td>'; ?>
```

Without the quotes, the PHP parser sees `&#10004;` as PHP code, which generates the syntax error.