# checkboxes condition is not working properly

Tags: php, html, mysql, tcpdf

I'm getting data from this function, now I want checked checkboxes based on my condition  and my condition is if I got value `roro` from db no will be checked if I got `Vessel, Containerized` yes will be checked.

```
$getDataForPDF = getDataForPDF($bookingsId, $bookingsLettersDockReceiptId);
if($getDataForPDF["typeOfMove"] == "Vessel, Containerized") {
     $checkedYes = "checked";
} if($getDataForPDF["typeOfMove"] == "roro") {
     $checkedNo = "checked";
}
```

and I'm using this condition in checkboxes

```
$html .= '<tr>';
     $html .= '<td colspan="3">';
          $html .= '<small>11. TYPE OF MOVE</small> <br />';
          $html .= $getDataForPDF["typeOfMove"];
     $html .= '</td>';

     $html .= '<td colspan="2">';
          $html .= '<small>11a. CONTAINERIZED &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (Vessel only)</small> <br/>';
          $html .= '<input type="checkbox" checked="'.$checkedYes.'" name="yes"> Yes &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" checked="'.$checkedNo.'" name="no"> No';
      $html .= '</td>';
$html .= '</tr>';
```

my condition is right but not working on `checked="checked"` condition. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Putting only `checked` attribute without value will make the `checkbox` to be checked anyway. Looks like you've hardcoded here the checked state of your checkboxes.

Comment: Also, if this is a `Yes/No` choice, why `checkbox` instead of `radio` buttons?

Comment: no its actually checkboxes. Please see my update question I also explan my condition in my question.

Comment: Ok, what about my first comment?

Comment: its mean that I've to put the checkboxes in my condtion?

Comment: Is your problem the checkboxes being checked despite your condition?

Comment: both of them are not checked. I'm getting `roro` in my db value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checked property is as simple as adding checked at the end of the tag.  For example `<input type="checkbox" name="yes" checked>` would be a checked box where the absence of checked would be unchecked.

The following code should solve the problem for you:

```
$checkedYes = '';
$checkedNo = '';
$getDataForPDF = getDataForPDF($bookingsId, $bookingsLettersDockReceiptId);
if($getDataForPDF["typeOfMove"] == "Vessel, Containerized") {
     $checkedYes = " checked";// note the space before checked
} if($getDataForPDF["typeOfMove"] == "roro") {
     $checkedNo = " checked";// note the space before checked
}


$html .= '<tr>';
     $html .= '<td colspan="3">';
          $html .= '<small>11. TYPE OF MOVE</small> <br />';
          $html .= $getDataForPDF["typeOfMove"];
     $html .= '</td>';

     $html .= '<td colspan="2">';
          $html .= '<small>11a. CONTAINERIZED &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (Vessel only)</small> <br/>';
          $html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="yes"'.$checkedYes.'> Yes &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="checkbox"  name="no"'.$checkedNo.'> No';
      $html .= '</td>';
$html .= '</tr>';
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o984L61e/

## Edit

Try changing the top code block to:

```
$checkedYes = '';
$checkedNo = '';
$getDataForPDF = getDataForPDF($bookingsId, $bookingsLettersDockReceiptId);
if($getDataForPDF["typeOfMove"] == "Vessel, Containerized") {
     $checkedYes = " checked='checked'";// note the space before checked
} 
if($getDataForPDF["typeOfMove"] == "roro") {
     $checkedNo = " checked='checked'";// note the space before checked
}
```

The [examples on tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_054.phps) use the `checked='checked'` property just like the other answers had, but you must initialize the variables before you try to concatenate in the html string.  As written in the question, either `$checkedYes` or `$checkedNo` will be undefined since they are being initialized in mutually exclusive `if` blocks.  Not sure if this will make a difference but it seems plausible.

Comment: its not working for me in TCPDF. TCPDF is not showing checkbox in TCPDF.

Comment: I am looking at some examples of TCPDF and added a tag to your question so that someone more experience in TCPDF may see the question.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try?

```
$getDataForPDF = getDataForPDF($bookingsId, $bookingsLettersDockReceiptId);
if($getDataForPDF["typeOfMove"] == "Vessel, Containerized") {
     $checkedYes = "checked='checked'";
} elseif($getDataForPDF["typeOfMove"] == "roro") {
     $checkedNo = "checked='checked'";
}
```

Along with:

```
$html .= '<input type="checkbox" '.$checkedYes.' name="yes"> Yes &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" '.$checkedNo.' name="no"> No';
```

I'm not sure it'd solve your problem but that is what you want to do in order the check the checkboxes accordingly to your database info.

Does it help?

Comment: What do you mean? What's the problem?

Comment: i'm checking the problem.

Comment: So, how does it look?

Comment: Its not creating checkboxes in PDF

Comment: its not working for me in TCPDF. TCPDF is not showing checkbox in TCPDF

Comment: It has to do with TCPDF then. Did the checkbox appear before?

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF's writeHTML() function only supports a limited subset of HTML tags.  Check the [writeHTML() documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ac3fdf25fcd36f1dce04f92187c621407) for details. The `input` tag is apparently one that is **not** supported.

Instead, you could use HTML entities to represent the checked and unchecked checkboxes.  There's already a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658044/tick-symbol-in-html-xhtml) that gives examples of possible entities you could use.