# Using jQuery to add a ✔ tick mark in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658044/tick-symbol-in-html-xhtml) I learned that the check mark is the code `✔ (0x2714 [HTML decimal: &#10004;])`. I know that you add text to a span using jQuery by doing `$('#spanid').text(texthere);`. I want to add the check mark to the span.

I did it like

```
$('#spanid').text(&#10004;); //This errors on the `&`
$('#spanid').text(#10004); //This results in `Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

What is the  correct way of doing this?

Comment: You have to use quotes around that. `text('&#10004;')`

Comment: tried it mate what appeared is the text `&#10004;` not a check mark. I want the check mark to appear not the text

Comment: Aaah yeah, then use `html`.

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/2bagqtsv/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.html()`. Also, enclose the value in quotes.

```
$('#spanid').html('&#10004;');
```

---

> `.text()` will convert the input to text string. `.html()` converts to HTML string/content and the character encoded can be seen.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rh3jr017/)

or if you already have the character `✔`, `.text()` would work;

```
$('#spanid').text('✔');
```

Comment: or if he wants to use .text(), it's still possible to use directly the char √

Comment: @ShaunakD yeah i didnt think of that i just though the code is the one to be used. but i got the idea now.

Comment: @Pekka, glad to help. I have been through this issue. There is always a scope of learning. :)

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is:

```
$('#spanid').addClass('check');
```

and add css;

```
.check:after {
  content: '(what ever the code for the check mark is)';
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution and technically still is a jQuery solution.

Comment: I like it more as you can remove is with jquery with .removeClass(''); Not that it is necessary in this situation. @Chad

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of using `content` in css but I must admit this is actually quite elegant compared to other uses I've seen. +1

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could create checkmark with `String.fromCharCode`:

```
$('#spanid').text(String.fromCharCode(10004));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#spanid').html ('&#10004;');
```

instead of `text()`. The text function escapes the string.